# How can I store a row of a 2d array in a variable in Java?

Tags: java, variables, multidimensional-array, rows

```
    int array[][] = {{2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 2, 12, 5, 7}, {2, 4, 5, 6, 10, 4, 36, 6, 9}, {4, 5, 5, 10, 2, 9, 4, 7, 12}};

    System.out.println("Seite1 " + " Seite2 " + " Seite3 " + " Dreieckstyp");
    dreieckstyp(array);

}

static void dreieckstyp(int arrays[][]) {
    for (int zeilen = 0; zeilen < arrays.length; zeilen++) {
        for (int spalten = 0; spalten < arrays[zeilen].length; spalten++) {
        }
    }

    int a = arrays[0][1];
```

Instead of just storing the 2 I would like to store in a the whole row: `2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 2, 12, 5, 7`
I already tried using **int a [] = array[0];** but that mess up with the code and I cant use the if statement: if ((a * a + b * b == c * c)) System.out.println(a + " \t\t " + b + " \t\t " + c + " \t " + " rechtwinkelig"); because the operator * cannot be applied to int[].  I want to prove the condition a² + b² = c²

Comment: It is recommended that you put the brackets right after the data type instead of after the variable name, that is, `int[][] array`, [see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a twodimensional array doesn't really exist in Java, it is just an array of arrays.

If you want to store a list into a variable, you'll need `a` to be an array:

```
int[] a = array[0];
```

Then if you want to operate on each value of `a`, you can just walk over all elements, like this:

```
for (int aa : a) {
    // Do something with aa
}
```

---

*By the way, you should give your variables descriptive names, the use of variables like `array` and `a` is not quite clear to future readers.*

Answer (score 1):

Just use :

```
 int a[] = array[0];
```

**Outputs**

```
[2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 2, 12, 5, 7]
```